# Can I have multiple OpenID accounts?

Tags: openid

I'm trying to understand OpenID better, and several questions are popping up in my head:

Is it all right to have multiple OpenID accounts, from different providers?

Is there any advantage or disadvantage to doing so? Would it cause any problems if they are unrelated to each other, or should (can?) they be linked together in some way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it all right to have multiple OpenID accounts, from different providers?

Yes.

> Is there any advantage or disadvantage to doing so?

Backup, I suppose. If a site ( such as Stack Exchange) supports an additional OpenID, if your primary OpenID goes down you can always rely on the alternating openID. This approach of course relies upon the target making use of multiple openIDs mapped to a single user account.

> Would it cause any problems if they are unrelated to each other, or should (can?) they be linked together in some way?

I would say no.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can have multiple OpenID accounts. What matters is their association with services. For example SE sites accept OpenID. You can login with your Google, Facebook, Blogger and many more of such accounts. You can even add OpenID's to be used with same service. SE and many other sites which support OpenID offer this feature too. To add an OpenID to SE just go to your profile and select add openid:

[image]

---

---

[image]

Enjoy the OpenID service to the full extent!